# Why are these fixed position DIV's not displaying in order of the Document flow?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs and the one that comes last in the source code appears on top on the webpage. I want them to display in their natural order. First DIV on top, second DIV below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="intro">    
  <h2>Gteaay Presents</h2>
  <h1 id="header-bigger">Producer World</h1>   
  <p class="header-smaller">For Producers by producers. A guide for choosing the right music composing software for you!</p>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">New Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="inspiration/">Inspiration</a></li>
    <li><a href="coupons.html">Coupons</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#intro {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0em 1em;
    background-image: url('images/gloomy-stripes-blue-lively.jpg');
    padding: 0;
    border-top: medium #0B9696 solid;
    border-bottom: medium #0B9696 solid;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav {
    background-color: black;
    height: 3em;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

PS This happened **AFTER** I made them `position: fixed;` Before that they were fine.
**EDIT** Actually DIV #2 appears **on top of** DIV #1 now.

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I clearified exactly what I want at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @MehulMohan Sorry but I hav'nt used fiddle in ages, I probably can't remember my username LOL.

Comment: You don't need an account to create fiddle ;)

Comment: @MehulMohan Oh! :) But it's OK now I solved my own question and I posted it right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, you are removing an element from the document flow. So in this case, the `#intro` is removed from the flow and the `#nav` moves into its place (try removing `position: fixed` from `#nav` only and see the difference).

Now `#nav` gets its own `position: fixed`, which removes that from the flow too, locking it in position. Only thing is, that location is the new, top-aligned one brought on by `#intro` having been taken out of the flow.

To solve the problem, you should have a single container holding both `#intro` and `#nav`, and apply the `position: fixed` to the container *only*.

Side-note: You're using `<h*>` tags wrong. "Gteaay Presents" should, at best, be in a `<div>` with bigger `font-size`.

Comment: OK. That is corerect and thanks for the tips on <h*> But I've just solved my own problem. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Your DIV #2 now appears on top of DIV #1 because DIV #2 is the last one declared in your HTML. to solve this problem, just add in your CSS (DIV #2): **z-index:-1;** or to DIV #1: **z-index:1;**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, `z-index` works for overlapping elements and it gives us the ability to decide which elements look like they're on top and which elements look like they're underneath. Like imagine you have bunch of magazines and some magazines are underneath other magazines and you can just see parts of each magazine. However I don't want these elements to overlap so `z-index` won't work here. I answered my own question so take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct solution to solving the problem and it takes the essential part of Niet's answer and incorporates it into my solution  here.

The reason this was "not working" was because when you use `position: absolute or position: fixed`, you are removing an element from the document flow. So in this case, the `#intro` is removed from the flow and the `#nav` moves into its place.

Also when you use a `position: fixed` we can also add a `specific`position using attributes like `top`, `left`etc.

So the solution is to give them a *specific* fixed position according to they're *new* position in the document flow.

e.g. for **#intro** `top: 10%` or `top: 10em;` or `top: 10px;` and then of course give **#nav** *another position* that *doesn't* overlap. e.g. `top: 20%` or `top: 20em` or `top: 20px`

PS I don't know if those values actually look right or work but I'm just demostrating the solution.

Comment: Incorrect. By default, it takes whatever position it was set in, and the reason for them being set at the top is described in the answer I gave you. To demonstrate, try giving `position: fixed` (with no `top`, `left` etc.) to an element further down the page.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried that. I don't understand but you're right. I'll re-read what you said and add it to my answer.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Correct.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Is my answer correct now? I accepted your answer but I want to keep my answer because it explains specifically what to do.

Comment: Well yes, but your answer is now basically a duplicate of mine, it has no reason for being...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Not quite. You didn't mentioned `position`attributes like `top` to move it to "correct" `specific`position. Also I edited my answer to show that I incorporated your answer into mine.